# Is it possible to set a post date for checks?

Tags: xrp

I'm trying to use checks in the XRP ledger (https://xrpl.org/use-checks.html) from post dated checks use case where the receiver can only pull the payment after a specific date.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with built-in Checks functionality at present.

Depending on your use case, you may be able to use a [time-held Escrow](https://xrpl.org/send-a-time-held-escrow.html).

Alternatively, if users are willing to trust an external service, you could write an app that only creates the Check (or Payment) after a specific date.